# DeadLock on Mysql using C# - "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, singleton, deadlock

We have this class to use like SingleTon to return the same connection and transaction(isolation level read commited)(we use CRUD):

```
public class SharedDbMySQL : DatabaseMySQL
{
    private static DatabaseMySQL sConn;

    private SharedDbMySQL()
    {
    }

    public static DatabaseMySQL GetInstance()
    {
        return GetInstance(TipoDados.Dados);
    }

    public static DatabaseMySQL GetInstance(TipoDados OpcoesBD)
    {
        if (sConn == null)
            sConn = new DatabaseMySQL(OpcoesBD);
        return sConn;
    }
}
```

With the SQL(microsoft)... the error dont occours... only the Mysql.
We insert first the "NotaFiscalEntrada"...
After we insert the products of this "NotaFiscalEntrada" on this method(and we have the error here):

```
public static void InsereAtualizaNotaFiscalEntradaProduto(List<nf_entrada_produto> entity, int IDNFEntrada, bool SharedConnection, bool LastOperation)
    {
        DatabaseMySQL db;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        if (SharedConnection)
            db = SharedDbMySQL.GetInstance();
        else
            db = new DatabaseMySQL();

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = db.Conn;
            cmd.Transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
            ONF_Entrada_Produto OpNFProduto = new ONF_Entrada_Produto(cmd);
            foreach (nf_entrada_produto Item in entity)
            {
                Item.ValorICMSST = 0;
                Item.IDNFEntrada = IDNFEntrada;
                Item.IDEmpresa = BusinessLogicLayer.ObjetosGlobais.DadosGlobais.EmpresaGlobal.ID;
                if (Item.ID == 0)
                {
                    if (!OpNFProduto.Add(Item))
                        throw OpNFProduto.LastError;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!OpNFProduto.Update(Item))
                        throw OpNFProduto.LastError;
                }
            }

            if (LastOperation || !SharedConnection)
            {
                db.CommitTransaction();
                db.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            db.RollBackTransaction();
            db.Disconnect();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The error is when we insert the Products (code above)
"Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction".
We found something about  the deadlock... the lost of the connection can be the error, how to resolve it?I think thats a server error? thanks all.

Comment: What is your wait_timeout setting?

Comment: Its up to 30 seconds... we changed it... to 1 minute... but the same error.

Comment: I talked to a friend... he explained me that a  DatabaseSQLServer db = new DatabaseSQLServer(); is one thing... the SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); is other... we are using the same DB but the cmd is created everytime.. for a deadlock problem can be resolved if we use the same CMD.... we are trying it right now

Comment: Can you run query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`? this should tell more exactly what the deadlock is...

Comment: If its alot of transacgions, try to commit more often, then the time the lock is active if far less.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was on the METHODS... I created again a new connection and not taking it from the singleton...
And the database deadlock the tables and other connections try to change it too... and there is the problems.

```
cmd.Connection = new db.Connect();
cmd.Connection = db.Conn;
```

replaced to

```
cmd.Connection = db.Conn;
```

Inside of class db(singleton):

```
MySqlConnection conn;

public MySqlConnection Conn
        {
            get
            {
                if ((conn == null) || (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed))
                {

                    Connect();
                }

                return conn;
            }
            set
            {
                conn = value;
            }
        }

public override void Connect()
        {
            RetornaDadosIniParaClasse();
            conn = new MySqlConnection(StringConnection);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    throw new AccessDatabaseException("Conexão com o banco de dados firebird fechada");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new AccessDatabaseException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

It taked a lot of time because its difficult to see the error... we debuged it a lot to find it.

Comment: And for some reason... the problem was only on MYSQL... MSSQL have no errors on it... i think the MSSQL level of interaction with c# have a mechanism to resolve problems like this for some reason.